# Problems starting Unity

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, startup

I am struggling to start unity because it keeps giving me the error "the application was unable to start correctly" the code 0xc000007b. I have tried replacing the 64 bit dlls for system32, and I have reinstalled visual c++ redistributables. I currently have an Asus zenbook 13 with windows 11. Please help me.

Comment: I know it's a cliché but do a full clean install - remove all traces of Unity / Visual studio and start again. Possibly use a good registry cleaner (e.g. CCleaner is pretty safe) before reinstalling. Recommend using Unity Hub as well, rather than a separate installer. https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download (Unity Hub button).

Comment: I did try unity hub but it wouldn't create a project. I will try to use CCleaner. thanks.

Comment: If you're totally stuck the Unity devs are pretty responsive so raise a support ticket with them